# how to redirect DNS to a domain and emails

Tags: web-services, dns, web-hosting, google-workspace

I have a domain that registered on company that just provide just domains, I made workspace google emails on that domain, and i have web host in small company.
I want buy web hosting on HostGator and redirect the domain and google emails there.
I know how to redirect domain to the HostGator DNS, but for the emails I don't know how

how can redirect the emails, will the emails stop working and for how long?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Domain names (website etc) work with A and CNAME records.
Emails work with MX records.

So, if your google MX records are set and working, all you need is to add A / CNAME records to get the website to work.

This will not cause any downtime at all.

Comment: just to make sure the domain right now on small web hosting company. is it still going to be the same process that in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to set MX records of your Google Mail server at your DNS zone. Because mail server uses MX records.

Thank you,
Harsh Sheth